# Welches Wort haben Sie als Kind für Fisch benutzt?

Tags: noun

Wenn ein Mensch älter wird, lernt er viele verschiedene Wörter für Tiere, die im Meer leben.

Mich interessiert ein allumfassendes Wort (wie ein Regenschirm oder die Wurzel eines Baumes). Normalerweise kennen Kinder das einfachste, abstrakteste Wort für Meeresfrüchte, Delfine, Wale, Haie oder Tintenfische.

Comment: Fisch?   Was sonst?

Answer (score 2):

Ich bin an der Ostsee aufgewachsen. Für die verschiedenen Tiere, die im Meer leben, hatten wir nie nur ein einziges Wort. Ich glaube, das ist eine erwachsene Vorstellung.

Fische kannte ich zuerst aus Büchern und als Mittagessen. Mein erstes Verständnis von "Fisch" bezog sich auf die äußere charakteristische Form. Die Vorstellung, dass es auch z.B. Wale und Delfine gibt, die zwar grob wie Fische aussehen, aber keine sind, kam erst deutlich später. Insofern ist "Fisch" eigentlich schon der oberste Oberbegriff, den ich früh gelernt habe.

Die ersten Tiere, die ich am Meer wirklich gesehen habe, waren keine Fische, sondern Quallen, Krebse und Krabben. Außerdem die Schalen von Muscheln am Strand, bei denen ich erst etwas später gelernt habe, wie das lebende Tier aussieht. Und es gab in der Stadt ein Becken mit Seehunden, die vom Wärter mit Heringen gefüttert wurden.

Das waren aber von Anfang an für uns Quallen, Krebse, Krabben, Muscheln und Seehunde, Oberbegriffe wie "Meerestiere" oder "Meeresfrüchte" kamen erst viel später dazu. Wir hätten die aber auch nie "Fische" genannt.

Answer (score 1):

So ganz verstehe ich verstehe die Frage nicht, aber ich versuche sie trotzdem zu beantworten. Wenn ich mich nur auf den Titel

> Welches Wort haben Sie als Kind für Fisch benutzt?

beschränke, so ist die Antwort einfach: **Fisch**.

Im Fragetext kommen auch Nicht-Fische vor, aber die Antwort ist nicht weniger banal. Zum Beispiel habe ich zu Muscheln **Muscheln** und zu Krebsen **Krebse** gesagt. Über die Existent von Walen und Delphinen habe ich überhaupt erst durch mein Kinderlexikon erfahren, und weil darin gleich erklärt wurde, dass sie keine Fische seien, habe ich sie von jeher **Wale** beziehungsweise **Delphine** genannt.

Alle zusammen waren für mich **Wassertiere**, aber definitiv nicht **Meerestiere**, denn die Erfahrung, dass es auch im Meer (genauer: der Ostsee) Fische, Muscheln und Krebse gibt, kam erst nach den vielen Angelausflügen mit meiner Familie an Flüssen (der Oder), Bächen, Seen, Tümpel … in der näheren Umgebung, wo ich zuerst auf diese Tiere gestoßen bin. Ich vermute allerdings, dass ich, wenn es im Gespräch überhaupt mal um Wassertiere im Allgemeinen ging, entweder einfach die mir bekannten Arten (Karpfen, Hechte, Aale, Plötzen, Muscheln, Krebse) aufgezählt oder schlicht und einfach **Fische**, **Muscheln** und **Krebse** gesagt habe, anstatt den Oberbegriff **Wassertiere** zu verwenden.

Comment: Diese Frage ist sicherlich von einem Bot gestellt worden.